# Trying to load icon from jar file

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to load icons from a jar file.   I have both tried to load it from classes within the jar file as well as classes outside the jar file.

outside of the jarfile -  returned a null exception

```
java.net.URL imageURL = LoadHTMLExample.class.getClassLoader()
    .getResource("icons/mouse.png");
```

in side of the jar file in the LoadHTMLExample

```
java.net.URL imageURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResource("icons/mouse.png");
```

get the same error.

I have also tried variations of 
"icons", "/icons" "icons/" "/icons/mouse.png" "icons/mouse.png"

nothing seems to work any idea

the icon is in the jar file

```
jar
 --icons --- {all the images}

 --com.blah.blah
```

Comment: Names are case sensitive in jar resource. Also a starting / maybe missing.

Comment: I have also tried variations of "icons", "/icons" "icons/" "/icons/mouse.png" "icons/mouse.png"

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem and I've tried all the same things as you mention, how did you resolve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I've always used the system class loader, whose path is relative to the root of the JAR:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("icons/mouse.png");
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Answer (score 5):

Skip the class loader, and get the resource as a stream instead. If you don't need the URL you can turn them directly into BufferedImages like so. I've left the stream and exception handling as a further exercise.

```
InputStream stream = LoadHTMLExample.class
    .getResourceAsStream( "/icons/mouse.png" );
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( stream );
```

---

Questioner needs the URL which brings us back to everyone else's suggestions. The images are definitely in the jar aren't they?

Comment: Class.getResourceAsStream() just delegates to the ClassLoader. It's essentially the same thing.

Comment: I need the URL, a webrenderobject is going to use the resource location to pull the icons

Comment: also tried you method, and image keeps is always null, so either way isn't working...what is blocking the reading of a jar file?

Answer (score 1):

I think that `getResource` gets the resource relative to the location of `LoadHTMLExample.class`.  So your `jarfile` should be structured in the following way:

```
myjar.jar
 |
 |- ...
 |- LoadHTMLExample.class
 |- ...
 \-- icons
      |
      \- mourse.png
```

Also, you might be getting stream through `getResourceAsStream` than getting the `URL`.

Comment: Alternatively, change the path from *icons/mourse.png* to */icons/mourse.png* (note the '/' at the beginning).

Comment: Everything else considered, you definitely need to do what Peter suggested, because to load "icons/mouse.png" means to load it relative to the class. In your JAR you have icons off the root, so you must prefix with a foreslash.

Comment: I got it to work!

 final java.net.URL imageURL3 = com.java.html.LoadHTMLExample.class.getResource( "icons/" );

that works for the above diagram

Answer (score 0):

Is the jar in question on the classpath of your runtime? I have a jar with PNGs in it, and I can recreate the nulls if I don't include it on the classpath. If the jar is there they go away.

Answer (score 0):

final java.net.URL imageURL3 = com.java.html.LoadHTMLExample.class.getResource( "icons/" );

works for the below directory structure

myjar.jar
 |
 |- ...
 |- LoadHTMLExample.class
 |- ...
 -- icons
      |
      - mourse.png

Thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("icons/mouse.png"));
```

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResource-java.lang.String-) of `getSystemResource()`:

> Find a resource of the specified name from the **search path used to load classes**...

This will find your icons even in a jar-file.