# How to load icon from resource in Java?

Tags: java, swing

> Possible duplication (solved): https://stackoverflow.com/a/1133132/783469

I have icons (jpg, png) for my application, which is stored in my directory `/var/tmp/gameXbox/src/image/<here>`. Now, How can i use them in application, without using hard link but as resource?

Example: not working

```
IconForMyButton = ImageIO.read(new File(
                    ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("image/button1.png")
                  ));
```

[image]

Works when i do with hard link:

```
IconForMyButton = ImageIO.read(new File(
                      "/var/tmp/gameXbox/src/image/button1.png"
                  ));
```

Comment: Make sure the images are contained in the classpath of your application, and use a relative link

Comment: What you do want to load? An image from classpath or filesystem? This is a difference. You're mixing both up.

Comment: @Google : Please do confirm first, You want to display this icon on your button, as your variable is suggesting. Am I right about that ?  Regards

Comment: @Michael-O: from classpath (filesystem is working for me, as above).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to load icon from jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133066/trying-to-load-icon-from-jar-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resource loading takes place in the classpath, relative to the current package.
If `/var/tmp/gameXbox/src/` is in your classpath, then:

```
ImageIO.read( ClassLoader.getSystemResource( "image/button1.png" ) );
```

However, usually the `src` folder is *not* included in the classpath by IDEs. Try adding the image to the `bin` folder.

Comment: project/build/classes/image/* exist. But not working. See my edit above.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I didn't even realize. You were trying to create a `File` object from an `InputStream` and I, from an `URL`.

Comment: import javax.imageio.*; (to use ImageIO)

Answer (score 6):

I usually use class.getResource for this kind of operation :

```
YourClass.class.getResource("image/button1.png")
```

i use it to retrieve the file from a jar archive but should work also to retrieve from filesystem resources.

Answer (score 0):

Images do not go into a source folder but into a resource folder. Fix your IDE and use Maven and it will work with `getResourceAsStream` with the current context classloader.