# Image won't load JButton

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, embedded-resource

I am trying to make a main menu and i am now working on the play button. Everything works fine except that it doesn't load an image. The image is in the source folder and this is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton play;
    
    GameFrame() {
        
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("playButton.png");
        
        play = new JButton();
        play.setBounds(500,100,250,100);
        play.addActionListener(this);
        play.setText("hi");
        play.setFocusable(false);
        play.setIcon(icon);
        
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(1000,700);
        this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        this.setUndecorated(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(play);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==play) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load icon from resource in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660945/how-to-load-icon-from-resource-in-java)

Comment: These answers might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4801386/4476582

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: `this.setVisible(true); this.add(play);` should instead be `this.add(play); this.pack(); this.setVisible(true);`. Setting the GUI visible should be last. After all components are added, but before the GUI is visible, call `pack()` to ensure the GUI is validated and sized to fin the content. The numbers in `this.setSize(1000,700);` are no better than a guess. `this.setLayout(null);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  ..

Comment: .. Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). `e.getSource()==play` Instead use `e.getSource().equals(play)` more more reliable comparison.