# JFrame design change after generating JAR file? Image missing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jar, embedded-resource

I have a little problem with Swing (or maybe netBeans), I was making a testing `JFrame`, I changed its background by an image with this line of code:

```
this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("src/testdesign/BG.png")))));
```

And I added a `JLabel` with an `Icon` to the frame using netBeans.
The result when compiling the project (In the IDE) was:

[image]

All is fine.. But when I generate a JAR file, the result is:

[image]

I'm not a Java pro, so I think that the way I changed the background isn't the proper way, or maybe it's another thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to load icon from jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133066/trying-to-load-icon-from-jar-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use incorrect way to load background image. In your code image location depends on project directory `src`. You should load image from classpath but file system. You `Class.getResource` method to fix it e.g.:

```
this.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(pathToImage))));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sergey, but I get an error : non static method cannot be re... from a static context... I put is in the constructor which is called from main (static), even if I put it in another methot all of them are called by main..