# Application icon not following the exported project?

Tags: java, swing

My application icon works fine when running the app from Eclipse, but once I export it as a runnable jar, then it doesn't appear.

This is the code I use to set the icon:

```
try {
    setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("resources/icons/icon.png")));
}
catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

The icon is in a source-folder called `resources/icons`.

Why doesn't the icon get included in the export?

Using URL now instead of looking for the icon with the `File` method. This works great!

Is it possible to change - by default - the file's icon? I think I have to use resource hacker or something like that in order to change it. But if it's possible via code, I'd love to learn it!

Comment: Did you insert the folder in your build or your export specification?

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: @IQV it's not an option, it seems like, in eclipse when exporting as a runnable jar!

Comment: @AndrewThompson this seems quite interesting, will look at this

Comment: When you export your jar, you click once "Next" in the wizard. The second window shows the "resources to export". When you open the tree of your project, is the resource-folder checked?

Comment: @IQV I don't have that window. This is what I get after pressing next on Runnable Jar: https://gyazo.com/655c2bbee790389f2ba2478491fdccc7

Comment: You get this window, when you use "JAR file" instead of "Runnable JAR file". Unfortunately I always use the first. I have never used the runnable jar file. Sorry.

Comment: @IQV doesn't work for me if it's not a runnable jar file, the app doesn't open :/ But I managed to solve it by using a URL anyways!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load icon from resource in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660945/how-to-load-icon-from-resource-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to load icon from jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133066/trying-to-load-icon-from-jar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getResource` instead of `new File()`, like this:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/icons/icon.png"));
```

So your `setIconImage` should be like so:

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/icons/icon.png")).getImage());
```

If your icon exit inside your package you can do like this:

```
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/icons/icon.png"));
```

So your `setIconImage` should be like so :

```
setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/icons/icon.png")).getImage());
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: *If your icon exit inside your package you can do like so: ..
`"/com/icons/icon.png"`" Actually, then it can be just `"icon.png"`whereas ``"com/icons/icon.png"`* is for a path **relative to the current package** (would not recommend) and `"/com/icons/icon.png"` is a path from the root of the class-path (most robust).